# Select one radio button out of each row of a list view from a radio group

Tags: android

I have rows in my list view. On each row I have two radio buttons , both in the same radio group.

The radio buttons are named "Full" and "Partial" . I want only one "Partial" to be selected across all rows in my list view and rest all needs to become "Full" .

So, when a user selects "Partial" on one and there is a previously marked radio button as "partial", it should change to "Full". Here I had tried but did not get desired output as I want.

```
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i)
                {
                    if(i==R.id.radio_partial_selection)
                    {
                        if (selected != null)
                        {
                            selected.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        holder.radioButton_partial.setChecked(true);
                        Log.d("selected=","11"+selected);
                        selected = holder.radioButton_partial;
                        Log.d("selected=","22"+selected);
                    }
                    if(i==R.id.radio_full_selection)
                    {

                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside your onCheckedListener, I would set a boolean that is switched when one of the partial buttons is checked. Then have the view check to see if the partial switch has been thrown. If it has, have the view display the "full" button instead of the partial button.

While I'm not familiar with radio buttons (I havent used them on android),
if necessary I can put together a bit of sample code for you.

Edit (Provided example code)

In your particular situation, this is how I would handle your issue. As stated throughout the comments of it, there are a few assumptions made (since I did not have your code)

```
public class sampleRadioButtonActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * When this is set to false, all radio buttons will show partial.
     * When this is set to true, all radio buttons will show full, except the one that is
     * set to show partial
     */
    private boolean showPartialOrFull;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /**
         * Do your on create stuff here
         */
        /**
         * We are setting the showPartialOrFull here to be false,
         * this will allow the view to show partial or full for now
         */
        showPartialOrFull = false;
        holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.radio_partial_selection){
                    showPartialOrFull = true;
                    changeRadioButtonToFull(holder);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Because I'm missing some code, assumptions are made here.
     * The first assumption is that the radio buttons are sitting in a viewgroup.
     * The second assumption, is more a recommendation, that you put the radiobuttons
     * in a ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher (I will be using the first).
     */
    private final void changeRadioButtonToFull(View viewToIgnore){
        for(int i = 0;  i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if(child != viewToIgnore){
                ((ViewFlipper) child).setDisplayedChild(R.id.radio_full_selection);
            }
        }
    }
```